# Добавление шрифтов в iTextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, itextsharp

Всем привет.
Создаю PDF документ через вертку HTML.
Столкнулся с проблемой.
Нет кирилицы в базовом шрифте.

Я подключил шрифт Arial.
Но, как я понял задать глобально шрифт в создаваемый документ нельзя.
Шрифт нужно постоянно добавлять в каждый new Phrase

Но так как я создаю документ по HTML, то для добавления строк в файл я не использую Phrase.

Код выглядит следующим образом...
Как туда подкинуть шрифт ?
Есть одна перегрузка с поддержкой шрифтов вроде как, но там еще надо указывать поток c CSS, до указания шрифтов, а его у меня нет

```
  {
        string textHtml = Properties.Resources.TransferForm.ToString();
      
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
            Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 25, 25);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, ms);

            string ttf = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), "ARIAL.TTF");
            var baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(ttf, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
            var font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(baseFont, iTextSharp.text.Font.DEFAULTSIZE, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);

            pdfDoc.Open();
            pdfDoc.Add(new Phrase("тест test", font));

            using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(textHtml))
            {
                XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, sr);
            }

            pdfDoc.Close();
            ms.Close();
            var fcr = File(ms.ToArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "test.pdf");
            return Task.FromResult(fcr);
        }
```

Comment: Хотя ответ тут оказался весьма очевидный. Можено же было подключить нужные шрифты прямо в CSS